# express-session: connection.sid cookie validation

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Recently we have discovered a auth vulnerability in our app becuause of the use of the `express-session` package.
Long story short, `express-session` uses the cookie `connection.sid` to manage its session and session's data.
What happens is that if two users (A and B) are authenticated and user **A** gets the `connection.sid` cookie of user **B**, user **A** will run a session as if he's user **B**- he'll have all user **B** privileges. In other words, user **A** is hijacking the session of user **B**

From reading over the web this is a known challenge. Is there any ways to mitigate it using `express-session` built-in functionalities? Or do I need to build an in-house middleware to act as an extra secure layer?

Comment: How did user A get sid of B ? Or are you saying express-session is generating duplicate sid ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev no, `express-session` does not duplicate identical session ids.
One option is that someone has stolen your `connection.sid` cookie.
In my case, no one has stolen the cookie but it seems like there are cases where user A sees user B info- assuming it could be either by bug or cookie settings.
Either way ,this raised another security leak that I want to manage within my application before fetching and showing the user data.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a vulnerability. That's the intended behaviour of cookies. Unless you meant that the site is vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting attacks. In that case check this: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html 

If somebody has access to a user's computer to steal cookies from it. You can't do much about that. You can however reduce the surface by adding subnet or origin nation to the session, so you can validate that it's being used from the same subnet/nation it was created in. User has to reauthenticate when they get an IP in a different subnet/nation